# Admin access with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a log in form for my admin pages and it works, but for now everyone who logs in can access those pages.

My users are also belong to usergroups and my users table in the database has a group_id column. The admin group has an id of 1.

What I'd like to do is that if someone who belongs to the admin group logs in can access the admin pages, but if the user belongs to a different group and tries to log in be redirected to main page or anywhere.

What I'm trying to do is add a similar code to the admin pages controllers

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // Access control
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('admin/login');
    }
}
}
```

My model

```
class Authenticate_model extends CI_Model {
    public function login_user($username, $password){
        //Secure password
        $enc_password = md5($password);

        //Validate
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$enc_password);

        $result = $this->db->get('users');

        if($result->num_rows() == 1){
            return $result->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself, provide validation and set $SESSION variable to retrieve if the user is logged in. But this is too much work, and error prone.
 I recommend you to use this popular library: https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth. It is really easy to set up, you just need to copy some files and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it your self(thats the question) then you need to store in SESSION two variables - logged_in and is_admin.

I would recomend two create library with function:

```
function is_logged_in($admin = FALSE){
   $is_logged = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   if($admin){
       $is_logged = $this->session->userdata('is_admin')
   }
   return $is_logged;
}
```

This assumes that you store two booleans "logged_in" and "is_admin" in SESSION.(If user has group_id = 1 then you would store TRUE in is_admin)

Then you can protect your site members only pages

```
if(!$this->your_authenticatation_library->is_logged_in()){redirect('notMembersControler')}
```

and admin page:

```
if(!$this->your_authenticatation_library->is_logged_in(TRUE)){redirect('notMembersControler')}
```

Thats the basic idea, you need to work around depending on what you are up to. Hope this helps!